# Prove that for $n\geq3$, $n^3\geq3n+5$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Prove that for $n\geq3$,$$n^3\geq3n+5$$

**My try:**

Let $f(x)=x^3-3x-5$. Clearly $x=1$ and $x=-1$ are critical points where $x=1$ is the local minima so the function $f(x)$ is an increasing function for $x>1$ and the result follows.

Please check and if possible provide another way to solve like induction. Thank you.

Comment: It's not enough if it's increasing, you also have to check that it is greater than zero after some time. But that is easy, since $f(3) = 13$, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using induction:

$1)$ For $n=3$ we get $3^3\ge 3\cdot 3+5=14$

$2)$ Hypothesis: $n^3\ge 3n+5$

$3)$ For $n+1$

$$(n+1)^3=n^3+(3n^2+3n+1)\ge 3n+5+(3n^2+3n+1)\\
(n+1)^3\ge [3(n+1)+5]+(3n^2+3n-2)\quad (1)$$

but

$$3n^2+3n-2=3n(n+1)-2\ge0\text{ for } n\ge 3$$

then from $(1)$ we get

$$(n+1)^3\ge 3(n+1)+5$$

Answer (score 3):

If $n=k+3$ with $k\ge0$, then

$$n^3=(k+3)^3=k^3+9k^2+27k+27\ge3k+14=3(k+3)+5=3n+5$$

Answer (score 1):

As $f'(x)=3(x^2-1)$, so for $x\geq 3$, $f'(x)\geq 0$ hence $f$ is increasing for all $x\geq 3$. Also observe that $f(3)=3^3-3.3-5\geq 0$. Now conclude your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like this.

$n(n^2-3)\geq3(3^2-3)=18\geq5$